# Use RichMap in Flink like Scala MapPartition

Tags: apache-spark, apache-flink, flink-streaming

In Spark, we have MapPartition function, which is used to do some initialization for a group of entries, like some db operation.

Now I want to do the same thing in Flink. After some research I found out that I can use RichMap for the same use but it has a drawback that the operation can be done only at the open method which will be at the start of a streaming job. I will explain my use case which will clarify the situtaion.

Example : I am getting data for a millions of users in kafka, but I only want the data of some users to be finally persisted. Now this list of users is dynamic and is available in a db. I wanted to lookup the current users every 10mins, so that I filter out and store the data for only those users. In Spark(MapPartition), it would do the user lookup for every group and there I had configured to get users from the DB after every 10mins. But with Flink using RichMap I can do that only in the open function when my job starts.

How can I do the following operation in Flink?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that what You want to do is stream-table join. There are multiple ways of doing that, but seems that the easiest one would be to use Broadcast state pattern [here](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/dev/datastream/fault-tolerance/broadcast_state/).

The idea is to define custom `DataSource` that periodically queries data from SQL table (or even better use CDC), use that `tableStream` as broadcast state and connect it with actual users stream.

Inside the `ProcessFunction` for the connected streams You will have access to the broadcasted table data and You  can perform lookup for every user You receive and decide what to do with that.